# Are dictionaries the presumed collection (array) in Xcode?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, dictionary

To use uisearchdisplaycontroller to specify a search on specific array fields, I found that the syntax caters only to key-value (dictionary?) data. Now, when I need to sort an array, I see again that the methods cater to key references, not mere array indexing. (I've built complex data with keyless arrays, not dictionaries.) Do I understand correctly that I should default to using dictionaries everywhere? Is there any situation to use plain arrays?

I see now the Key-Value Coding Guide (document 1812 of 3894)... should get to it any minute now.

Answer (score 1):

It is NOT mandatory but it will be much comfortable when using NSDictionary.

Also, with the plain array, you can sort it as well without using "%K" at predicate format or using block comparator